# 14.04, b43 and DE regulatory domain

Tags: wireless, 14.04, broadcom

I'm running 14.04 on a Compaq V6000 laptop which has a BCM4311 b/g wireless adapater, using the b43 firmware and proprietary blob (fwcutter).

On power-up, seemingly no matter what I do, the regulatory domain ends up being Germany. (I'm in Canada).

I can use `sudo iw reg set CA` to force it to Canada, but I haven't been able to find a way to make it persistent - it always boots up German.

How can I make this setting persistent, or set up some script to automagically change it to CA at the appropriate time during boot?

EDIT: Tried adding `REGDOMAIN=CA` to `/etc/default/crda` - no luck, and crda complains about 'country not being set' if I try to call it on its own. `iw reg set` appears to be the only way to make the change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix appears to be a combination of:

- adding `REGDOMAIN=CA` to `/etc/default/crda`
- adding `COUNTRY=CA` to `/etc/environment`

Now on bootup the world domain is set, followed by the Canadian limits.